# Group by time range query in mysql produces error

Tags: mysql, sql

i have used the following query to get time range based count. subtract currentime from created time but it produces an error

> Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'TO 8 then '8Hrs'
>           WHEN round(time_to_sec(timediff(now() , `created_date_t' at line 4

```
SELECT t.range, count(*) as num
FROM (
SELECT CASE
    WHEN round(time_to_sec(timediff(now() , `created_date_time`))/3600) BETWEEN 0 TO 8 then '8Hrs'
    WHEN round(time_to_sec(timediff(now() , `created_date_time`))/3600) BETWEEN 9 TO 16 then '16Hrs'
    WHEN round(time_to_sec(timediff(now() , `created_date_time`))/3600) BETWEEN 17 TO 24 then '24Hrs'
    WHEN round(time_to_sec(timediff(now() , `created_date_time`))/3600) > 24 then 'G24Hrs'
    AS range
    FROM `ticket`
)  as t     
GROUP BY range
```

And i have to avoid repetion of

```
round(time_to_sec(timediff(now() , created_date_time))/3600)
```

statement.

### table structure

```
id  created_date_time   issue   
-------------------------------------
1   2011-12-07 05:29:28 test  
2   2011-12-08 07:56:15 test  
3   2011-12-08 05:56:15 test
```

### create query

```
CREATE TABLE `ticketingsystem`.`ticket` (
`id` bigint( 20 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`created_date_time` datetime NOT NULL ,
`issue` text NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1
```

## I want below output

these fields are no of records has pending time since record created

```
8hrs    16hrs   24hrs   >24hr
---------------------------------
3       2        6      4
```

Comment: What is the error message you're getting? If you add that to your question post it may help people to answer.

Comment: @bouteillebleu i have added error message to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of mistakes in your query, so I've rewritten it all instead.

First of all, I suggest you create a `VIEW`. This is a one time thing.

```
CREATE VIEW ticket_wait AS
  SELECT HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), created_date_time)) AS hdiff
  FROM ticket;
```

After this, you can use the following query to get your results.

```
SELECT COUNT(hdiff) count,
  CASE
    WHEN hdiff BETWEEN 0 AND 8 THEN '8Hrs'
    WHEN hdiff BETWEEN 9 AND 16 THEN '16Hrs'
    WHEN hdiff BETWEEN 17 AND 24 THEN '24Hrs'
  ELSE '>24Hrs'
END `range`
FROM ticket_wait
GROUP BY `range`
```

By using the above query on the table

```
+----+---------------------+-------+
| id | created_date_time   | issue |
+----+---------------------+-------+
|  1 | 2011-12-10 07:06:44 | foo   |
|  2 | 2011-12-08 04:29:28 | foo   |
|  3 | 2011-12-08 23:29:28 | foo   |
|  4 | 2011-12-08 14:29:28 | foo   |
|  5 | 2011-12-09 12:29:28 | foo   |
|  6 | 2011-12-09 17:29:28 | foo   |
|  7 | 2011-12-09 23:29:28 | foo   |
|  8 | 2011-12-10 06:29:28 | foo   |
|  9 | 2011-12-10 04:29:28 | foo   |
| 10 | 2011-12-10 01:29:28 | foo   |
+----+---------------------+-------+
```

Your output will be

```
+-------+--------+
| count | range  |
+-------+--------+
|     1 | 16Hrs  |
|     1 | 24Hrs  |
|     5 | 8Hrs   |
|     3 | G24Hrs |
+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Your answer has the same mistake.

Comment: What mistake? I removed the second part of my question, I'll edit it again in a moment.

Comment: You just deleted it but it's on the history. Correct it and post it, that was a good recommendation

Comment: Thanks for your response,I tried and got this message "Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'then '8Hrs'
    WHEN HOUR(TIMEDIFF(created_date_time,NOW()) BETWEEN 9 AND 16 the' at line 4"

Comment: Add your table structure and desired output to the question.

Answer (score 2):

As well as Kristian's observation about `BETWEEN X AND Y`, you're missing the `END` from your `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN ...
    WHEN ...
END AS `RANGE` -- Note the END!
FROM ...
```

Comment: `RANGE` has to be encapsulated in ticks, since it's a reserved keyword.

Comment: or doublequotes, depending on the settings.

Comment: Good point - edited answer to include backticks around `RANGE`